# Django admin 'Now' button wrong timezone

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I'm getting the browser time when I click the 'Now' button on the Django admin page for a DateTimeField.  I did some research and it appears this was fixed in Django 1.7 (reference: http://bit.ly/1d2zqRa - I'm running 1.7.8).

Here is the model in models.py I have:
class WorkWindow(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

In admin.py I have:
admin.site.register(WorkWindow)

In settings.py I have:
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

This appears to be exactly the same problem as what was fixed here: http://bit.ly/1GtJ8Xr.  Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/ ? If you want better Timezone support on Django, you need to install pytz.

Comment: pytz is installed.  Besides having it installed, does anything special have to be done to make use of it?  In this case, the only time I'm setting the time is on the admin page.